# BeatifulSoup: detect where my script is being launched from(Europe, USA,...)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

BeautifulSoup extraction scrip fail when its run from a USA server and work when its run from Europa Server. The reason is that if you access the website from europe it has a different configuration than if you access it from another part of the world.

The following code extract information froma web-page and save it in a dataframe

I have the following code that work fine from my laptop.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def crawl(page):
    url = "https://www.bookdepository.com/category/352/Science-Fiction/browse/viewmode/all?page=" + str(page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser") 
    results = soup.find(class_='tab search')
    books = results.find_all(class_='book-item')
    
    return books


def books_info_to_table(page_info):
    book_table = []
    for book in page_info:
            title = book.find(class_='title').text.strip()
            author = book.find(class_='author').text.strip()
            isbn = book.find("meta", itemprop="isbn")["content"]
            discount_text = book.find(class_='price-save').text.strip() if book.find(class_='price-save') is not None else None
            discount = float(discount_text.split()[1].replace(",", ".")) if discount_text is not None else 0
            price_text = book.find(class_='sale-price').text.strip() 
            price = float(price_text.split()[0].replace(",", ".")) if price_text is not None else 0
            book_row = [isbn, title, author, price, discount]
            book_table.append(book_row)
    return book_table
```

convert results into a dataframe:

```
main_table = []
for x in range(1, 2):
    page = crawl(x)
    columns_name = ['isbn', 'title', 'author', 'price', 'discount']
    page_book_table = books_info_to_table(page)
    main_table += page_book_table
    
df_books = pd.DataFrame(main_table, columns=columns_name)
df_books.head()
```

When I upload that code and run it in Kaggle(apparently it run from USA) it doesn´t work anymore.. debuging the code its says:
`could not convert string to float: 'US$7.99'`

Very interesting because when I was running from my laptob(place on Germany) I sow the price in Euros `9,60 €` and worked fine but when the price its in Dollars doesn´t work anymore.

My script is adapted to what I saw from my screen and I didn't know that running from another part of the world would be different.

**Here is my question:**
In order to capture the error. There is a way to identify whether the script is being called from Europe or from the USA ?

I m not interested to fix the code but to know from where the are calling my script. Is there any way to find out ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace the values you dont want there:

```
price = float(price_text.replace("US$", "").replace("€","").replace(",","."))
```

Sorry this did not answer your actual question.

You could check the timezone of the machine maby?
this is what my machine gives

```
>>> import time
>>> time.tzname
('Romance Standard Time', 'Romance Summer Time')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, that is a solution of course !! Sorry I didnt specify it before, but my question was more in the direction "There is a way to identifyy if I m called from USA or EU or wherever", in our case change the "US$" for "€" but imagine that in the USA version would change anothers thing.

Comment: Im not replaceing $US with  € im first tryin to replace "US$" with "" and then "€" with "" but ive added an other solution you can try

Comment: Thanks for the 2 solution as well Bendik, I will let the question open just to see if anybody else knows any hide trick about that... "adding the code XXX return from where is the code run from